# T-SQL INSERT, UPDATE with IF ... ELSE помощь нужна, думаю вопрос не слабый.

Tags: mysql, sql

Суть проблемы такая, **при написании процедуры Insert and Update нужно условие**, такое что, при вызове этой процедуры через exec выполнялось условие.
Условие простое, имеются, к примеру 5 колонок, необходимо при вставке вставить 3 из 5, остальные 2 нужно чтоб заполнились Null. Если процедура Update, то при изменении 2х колонок 3 остальные не менялись. Если не понятен вопрос, разжую по лучше)) нужны идеи, выручайте :)

Answer (score 1):

INSERT

Сделать NULL значением по умолчанию для соответствующих столбцов.

UPDATE

Если вы измените значения в двух столбцах, то остальные меняться не будут по определению.